# the html page with multi row popup

Tags: jquery

Need help to make the URL1 (in first row) and URL2 (in second row) 
a hyperlink that will fetch information from an external url(http:example.com?page1) and show in a popup. The URL for second row will be http:example.com?page2.

```
Here is the code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-grid-b">
  <div class="ui-block-a" style="border:0px solid black; width:90px;"><span> col1 </span></div>
  <div class="ui-block-b" style="border:0px solid black; width:80%; height:100%;"><span>
    Test col2 test twt test test test test test  999 
  </span></div>
  <div class="ui-block-c" style="border:0px solid black; width:10px;"> URL1</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-b">
  <div class="ui-block-a" style="border:0px solid black; width:90px;"><span> col1 </span></div>
  <div class="ui-block-b" style="border:0px solid black; width:80%; height:100%;"><span>
    Test col2 test twt test test test test test  999
  </span></div>
  <div class="ui-block-c" style="border:0px solid black; width:10px;">URL2</div>
</div>
</body> </html>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do ? clarify it.

Comment: need to make a column in each row a hyperlink which when clicked will pull up an external URL (say, http:example1.com) inside a popup

Comment: I tried the below but is slow.<a href="#popup1" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-mini=true data-theme="a" data-inline="true" onclick="$('#popup1').popup(); $('#popup1').popup('open');">Information</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popup1" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="15,15" data-transition="slide">
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
 <iframe src="http://example.com/test.php?row=2" width="680" height="320" seamless></iframe>
</div>